# Windows 7 + Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 Horrible font rendering

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, fonts

popular sites such as CNN.com render text like crap in Chrome. Text looks great in IE9.. Here is a screenshot from an article off of CNN.com.

[image]

This seems to be a google web font called Lato.. This is a snippet of the css file from cnn.com.

```
@font-face {


font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/9k-RPmcnxYEPm8CNFsH2gg.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/wkfQbvfT_02e2IWO3yYueQ.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692). You can try [gdipp](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/) or [MacType](http://code.google.com/p/mactype/).

Comment: yeah when developing apparently you throw the svg file first in css in order for this bug in chrome. Most developers dont do this however.. Ive always gotten the issue for some reason. Not sure why. MacType fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Mac like Font rendering using GDI+.

[Here is an example on Lifehacker.](http://lifehacker.com/5190607/gdi%252B%252B-adds-os-x-font-rendering-to-windows)